# How to save Windows license before installing Ubuntu

Tags: multi-boot, partitioning, windows, thinkpad

I purchased a new Lenovo Thinkpad L540 laptop. This laptop was supposed to be installed with Windows 8 pro but instead it came with Windows 7 Pro with an option to upgrade to windows 8 Pro. Now they provided me four discs with following titles:

1. Operating System Recovery Disc Windows 8 Pro Disc 1
2. Operating System Recovery Disc Windows 8 Pro Disc 2
3. Windows 8 Recovery Media for Windows 8 Products Disc 1
4. Windows 8 Recovery Media for Windows 8 Products Disc 2

Now I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 on this laptop. Also I want to backup my license of Windows 7 so in case if in future if I need I'll install Windows 7 and not Win 8. I don't like Windows 8, I don't like Win 7 either but if I have to choose between them I'll choose 7.

Another problem I am facing is when I tried to shrink my 500GB windows partition I am not able to shrink it below 228 GB. I want to shrink it to 100GB so that I can use remaining 128 GB as my home partition. I followed [this][1] tutorial to shrink partition, but no luck. So I think I may have to remove Windows 7 and reinstall it using the backup I am creating above.

So can anyone please help me in telling me how can I create backup of Windows 7 before I start messing up by installing Ubuntu. I am in no rush, I want to know exactly what I am getting into, so I'll do as much reading as required. So pointing me in right direction will also help.

Thanks.

Comment: "How do I save my Windows 7/8 license" or "how do I deal with various Windows licensing issues" are probably outside the scope of this site.

Comment: Windows includes a backup tool: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/back-up-programs-system-settings-files#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 1):

If there is no license key that came with the media or on a sticker on the laptop you can most likely use [Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html) to get the key.  It is free and is pretty good at finding license keys for most popular software products.

Another option would be to use an imaging tool like [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).  You can make an image of the hard drive with Windows 7 and then restore it as necessary.